# RPG Damage Calculations?

Tags: java, math, random, generator

I am making a small RPG using Jcreator.

I give whatever character you pick damage at the start, we will take the Swordsman as an example.

I gave him 10 Damage and for the hitting damage I made the `int` `Hit`.

My problem is that this random number is not working well for damage as it is giving me damage under the actual attack range.

```
Hit = 1 + (int) ((Math.random() * (Damage - 1)) +1);
```

Comment: I can't comprehend what you're asking here...  random() * Damage will, by definition, result in a value less than Damage.

Comment: Do you want 10 to be the minimum damage, and have a chance to get higher?

Comment: No 10 is the average damage,I Want 5 more and 5 less,I Havent programmed in a while so im kind of shaky

Comment: @user3670236 To clarify, you have `int` `Damage` equal to `10`, and you want `Hit` to be within the range of `5 - 15`; do you want the range in general to be from `Damage/2` to `3 * Damage/2`? Or do you want the range to be from `Damage - 5` to `Damage + 5`? Like, if `Damage` was 20, would you want the range to be `10 - 30` or `15 - 25`?

Comment: use nextInt from java.util.Random http://ideone.com/AyyTHB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys,i understand random number generators a bit better now ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always know the bounds of your random number generator.

In pseudocode, to generate a number from a random space with a minimum and maximum,

```
Result = Minimum + (Maximum - Minimum) * (Random() - RandMin) / (RandMax - RandMin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
hit = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
```

where range = the max value you want minus the min value you want, i.e.,

```
int range = (max - min) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, and give you a number in the range of 5 above or below your damage:

```
randomNum = Damage-5 + (int)(Math.random()*Damage+1);
```

I tested it and it seems to have worked for me, didn't get a number below 5 or greater than 15